# Mysql replication failed after changes on master scheme

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-replication

I have master-slave replication from server with MariaDB (master) to server with Mysql (slave). All work fine, but when i change scheme of master, i have error on slave and replication broken after it.
How i can change my master scheme without errors on my slave?

Comment: What is "master scheme"?

Comment: I mean, db structure, if i change tables or add some columnd and s.o. replication will be broken.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, you must think about how to roll out schema changes.

- Never do `SELECT * ...` unless you are debugging or fetching into an associative array.  Else, extra columns can break things.
- Coordinate the rollout of code with schema changes.
- Take a downtime.

For complex rollouts, with minimal downtime:

1. Change code to handle discover and handle *either* schema (extra/missing columns, one table split into two, etc)
2. Change the schema and wait for it to propagate to all the Slaves.
3. Clean up the code (to handle only the new schema).

Answer (score 0):

1. Running an “ALTER TABLE” in MySQL to add additional columns and indexes locks the table and can result in breaking of the replication. The following are two ways to make schema changes without breaking the replication:  1.Wait for the schema change to replicate to all the slaves and no other queries are executed on master till the schema changes are applied throughout.An ALTER executed on the master will apply the changes to the table and can take a considerable amount of time depending on the table size. During this application time, the tables will be blocked for both reads and writes. Check on the slaves if the schema changes have been replicated and resume the operations on MySQL server thereafter.
2. Swap the Master and Slave server.  Stop Replication on one of the Slaves(refer to this as ‘Server A’) and apply the schema changes to the required tables. Make the current master(refer to this as ‘Server B’) a slave of the ‘Server A’ such that now ‘Server B’ and ‘Server A’ are in Master-Master replication. Wait till both the Servers are in-sync and then execute “STOP SLAVE”  on ‘Server A’ making it the new master Server."